# Apposition of Eintönigkeit and Schwarz in this translation of Camus's The Stranger

Tags: grammatical-case

The question is on the use of (grammatical) cases in the highlighted sentence below.  (The passage is from Georg Goyert and Hans Georg Brenner's translation of Camus's The Stranger.)

> Es schien mir, als bewegte sich der Leichenzug ein wenig schneller. Um mich herum war immer noch die gleiche leuchtende, prall mit Sonne gefüllte Landschaft. Der Glanz des Himmels war unerträglich. Einmal kamen wir über ein Stück Straße, das kürzlich ausgebessert worden war. Die Teerdecke war in der Sonne aufgeweicht. Die Füße versanken in ihr und rissen tiefe Wunden in ihr glänzendes Fleisch. Über dem Wagen wirkte der blanke Lederhut des Kutschers, als wäre er aus diesem schwarzen Brei geformt. **Ich kam mir zwischen dem blauen und weißen Himmel und der Eintönigkeit dieser Farben, dem klebrigen Schwarz des Teers, dem stumpfen Schwarz der Trauerkleider und dem blanken Schwarz des Leichenwagens, ein wenig verloren vor.**

**Question**

1. Am I suppose to parse the sentence as follows:

> Ich kam mir zwischen (1) [dem blauen und weißen Himmel] und (2) [(2a) {der Eintönigkeit dieser Farben}, (2b) {dem klebrigen Schwarz des Teers, dem stumpfen Schwarz der Trauerkleider und dem blanken Schwarz des Leichenwagens}], ein wenig verloren vor.

where (2a) and (2b) stand in apposition, or schematically:

> (2a) der Eintönigkeit dieser Farben = (2b) dem klebrigen Schwarz des Teers, dem stumpfen Schwarz der Trauerkleider und dem blanken Schwarz des Leichenwagens

This way, *zwischen* can govern *Eintönigkeit* and the three instances of *Schwarz*, which are all in the dative.

But we pay the cost of setting *Eintönigkeit* (not a color) apposite to *Schwarz* (a color).

2. From a purely grammatical point of view, could the sentence have gone instead:

> Ich kam mir zwischen dem blauen und weißen Himmel und der Eintönigkeit dieser Farben, **des** klebrigen Schwarz(**es**) des Teers, **des** stumpfen Schwarz(**es**) der Trauerkleider und **des** blanken Schwarz(**es**) des Leichenwagens, ein wenig verloren vor.

Basically I have tried to set two similar things in apposition, *Farben* and *Schwarz*, by changing the latter's case.  (I have added *es* in parentheses because [this Wiktionary entry](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Schwarz) gives two alternative genitive forms for the word.)

3. If yes to 2, how bad or not bad does this new sentence sound?  (In English, *the monotony of the sticky black of the tar* seems to sound OK.)

**Background**

Camus's original goes like this:

> J’étais un peu perdu entre le ciel bleu et blanc et la monotonie de ces couleurs, noir gluant du goudron ouvert, noir terne des habits, noir laqué de la voiture.

Not that I think a translation should try to mirror the original in every way it can.

Another translator (Uli Aumüller) seems to have made a similar adjustment:

> Ich war ein bißchen verloren zwischen dem blauweißen Himmel und der Monotonie dieser Farben, dem klebrigen Schwarz des aufgerissenen Teers, dem matten Schwarz der Kleider, dem Lackschwarz des Wagens.

Comment: Note "zwischen" does not necessarily require a.*pair* of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also parse the sentence in the way you outlined along and around question one. I also think that it mirrors the French original well. However, please pardon my French, it is not as good as my German or my English.

I also feel that using the genitive for the colours, and thereby putting them in apposition to the word *colours*, i.e. have them be a subdivision of *monotony*, works, too. I don’t question the sentence and I don’t feel it sounds bad.

For some reason not entirely known to me, I would have gone with the dative for the colours, too, if I had to write the text from scratch.